What does one contemplate to become a sotāpanna?
What does a Buddhist practitioner, based on the 8 fold path, and deepening practice contemplate to become a sotāpanna (a stream-enterer)?

In order to become stream enterer one should meditate on Four Nobel Truths. Three marks of existence should be perceived directly. Stream enterer should abandon 3 fetters namely, self view, doubt on the teachings ,attachment to rituals and rites. Stream enterer should contemplate on dependent origination.
(I am not an official stream enterer but I meditate often.)

The [tag:reference-request] tag under the question conventionally means that the OP is looking for "references" e.g. links to suttas or other literature.

AN 3.86 says about stream-entry:

There is the case where a monk is wholly accomplished in virtue,
moderately accomplished in concentration and moderately accomplished
in discernment... With the wasting away of [the first] three fetters (self-identity view, doubt, misapprehending the role of precepts & rules),
he is a stream-winner (sotāpanna), never again destined for states of woe,
certain, headed for self-awakening.
AN 3.86

SN 56.11 says about stream-entry:

Now this, bhikkhus, is the noble truth of the origin[ation] of suffering: it
is this craving which leads to renewed existence, accompanied by
delight and lust, seeking delight here and there; that is, craving for
sensual pleasures, craving for existence, craving for extermination.
Now this, bhikkhus, is the noble truth of the cessation of suffering: it is the remainderless fading away and cessation of that same craving, the giving up and relinquishing of it, freedom from it, nonreliance on it.
And while this discourse was being spoken, there arose in the Venerable Kondañña the dust-free, stainless vision of the Dhamma: “Whatever is subject to origination is all subject to cessation."
SN 56.11

SN 12.28 says about stream-entry:

When, bhikkhus, a bhikkhu thus understands aging-and-death, its
origin, its cessation, and the way leading to its cessation; when he
thus understands birth ... existence ... clinging ... craving ...
feeling ... contact ... the six sense bases ... name-and-form ...
consciousness ... formations, their origin, their
cessation, and the way leading to their cessation, he is then called a
bhikkhu who is accomplished in view, accomplished in vision, who has
arrived at this true Dhamma, who sees this true Dhamma, who possesses
a trainee’s knowledge, a trainee’s true knowledge, who has entered the
stream of the Dhamma, a noble one with penetrative wisdom, one who
stands squarely before the door to the Deathless.
SN 12.28

SN 13.1 says about stream-entry:

The Buddha, picking up a little bit of dirt under his fingernail,
addressed the mendicants: “What do you think, mendicants? Which is
more: the little bit of dirt under my fingernail, or this great
earth?”
“Sir, the great earth is far more. The little bit of dirt under your
fingernail is tiny. Compared to the great earth, it’s not nearly a
hundredth, a thousandth, or a hundred thousandth part.”
“In the same way, for a noble disciple accomplished in view, a person
with comprehension, the suffering that’s over and done with is more,
what’s left is tiny. Compared to the mass of suffering in the past
that’s over and done with, it’s not nearly a hundredth, a thousandth,
or a hundred thousandth part, since there are at most seven more (sattakkhattuṁparamatā)
[fetters]. That’s how very beneficial it is to comprehend the teaching
and gain the vision of the teaching.”
SN 13.1

SN 25.10 says about stream-entry:

Monks, form is inconstant, changeable, alterable. Feeling...
Perception... Fabrications... Consciousness is inconstant, changeable,
alterable.
One who knows and sees (pajānāti passati) that these phenomena are
this way is called a stream-enterer, steadfast, never again destined
for states of woe, headed for self-awakening.
SN 25.10

MN 115 says about all Noble Ones, including stream-enterers:

“Here, Ānanda, a bhikkhu understands: ‘It is impossible, it never
happens, that a person whose view is perfected should treat any
formation as permanent — no such possibility is found’, and he
understands: ‘It is possible that an ordinary man should treat any
formation as permanent — such a possibility is found.’
“He understands: ‘It is impossible, it never happens, that a person
whose view is perfected should treat any formation as pleasurable — no
such possibility is found’, and he understands: ‘It is possible that
an ordinary man should treat any formation as pleasurable — such a
possibility is found.’
“He understands: ‘It is impossible, it never happens; that a person
whose view is perfected should treat any dhamma as self — no such
possibility is found’, and he understands: ‘It is possible that an
ordinary man should treat any dhamma as self — such a possibility is
found.’
MN 115

Therefore, a Buddhist practitioner, based on the 8 fold path, and deepening practice, must contemplate/directly see the following to become a sotāpanna (a stream-enterer):

The cessation of craving (as explained in the Four Noble Truths) brings peace. This removes the fetter of doubt about what the Path is.

The cessation of the craving, attachment, becoming, self-identity-birth & self-identity-death (explained in Dependent Origination) brings peace. This removes both the fetter of doubt and the fetter self-identity view. It also removes wrong views about the role & results of kamma because it is directly seen kamma only occurs & has result when there is attachment.

The cessation or letting go (vossagga) of craving naturally develops samadhi (per SN 48.10). This samadhi allows the mind to lucidly contemplate the nature of the five aggregates, namely, each of the five aggregates is impermanent, cannot bring happiness (dukkha) & is not-self. This right view again brings peace by causing the cessation of craving, disenchantment & dispassion (refer to SN 22.59) towards the five aggregates. The sotapanna directly knows the only reliable secure safe happiness is non-craving & non-attachment towards the five aggregates, which is the 'unconditioned'. Therefore, a sotāpanna also does not go literally insane making countless posts on the puthujjana internet about 'jhana' imaginings.

Thus a stream-enterer can also contemplate a taste of the sphere of the Arahants: "This is peaceful; this is sublime — that is, the calming of all activities, the letting go of all attachments, the ending of craving, fading away (dispassion), cessation, extinguishment (Nibbana)" (AN 10.60).



I guess also the right view sutta MN 9, is a good guide, as it shows one doesn't need to contemplate everything, with each view listed one can realise stages of enlightenment. As for some giving too many instructions can lead to confusion. I like that sutta as it shows a bunch of ways people might come to know right view. Though I do agree with your suttas :-), I wonder about the 4 noble truths though, in how they relate to path factors.

AN 10.92 lists out the criteria for stream entry:

Five forms of fear and animosity are stilled (basically the five precepts)
Four factors of stream entry (verified confidence in the Buddha, Dhamma and Sangha, and having virtues appealing to the noble ones)
Rightly seen and rightly ferreted out the noble method (dependent origination)

And also:

“Sāriputta, they speak of a ‘factor of stream-entry’. What is a factor
of stream-entry?”
“Sir, the factors of stream-entry are associating with good people,
listening to the true teaching, proper attention, and practicing in
line with the teaching.”
SN 55.5

Please read "Into the Stream" by Ven. Thanissaro and also watch the YouTube video talk "Characteristics of a Sotapanna" (by Ven. Dhammavuddho).
The video talk discusses SN 55.5 in detail.

Apparently there are different ways to get to the same place, but when something is emphasized, it must be important:

For a monk practicing the Dhamma in accordance with the Dhamma, what accords with the Dhamma is this:
that he keep cultivating disenchantment with regard to form... feeling... fabrications... consciousness. -SN 22.39
22.40 that he keep focused on inconstancy with regard to form, [etc.]
22.41 that he keep focused on stress with regard to form, [etc.]
22.42 that he keep focused on not-self with regard to form, [etc.]

I've heard that in the Thai Forest Tradition, new monks are taught to examine the hair of the head, hair of the body, nails, teeth and skin. I assume that's because it's easy to see that your self is not contained inside a toenail, but a toenail is still part of the body, made of food, so when you consider the brain, heart, etc., it's easier to see that those parts too are not a self. Brain and toenail are both made of the four great elements.
The same can be applied to the mental aggregates, and teachers explain how to examine and take apart your experience into the smaller and smaller pieces it's made of, to see how no self can be found in them, and if it's not in the parts, it can't be in the whole either.
They also teach about getting in the habit of seeing how everything is transient, constantly changing, which means it can't be held onto, and is therefore not worthy of being clung to or seen as constituting a self. There are some suttas that use a systematic question and answer method to teach along these lines, and the ones I know of are SN 22.83, 22.85, 22.100, MN 35, MN 109, and MN 106.
This gives another way to contemplate anatta:

[Ven. Ananda] was a willing and diligent pupil and was able to attain the fruit of stream-entry already during his first rains retreat. Later Ananda told his fellow monks, that the venerable Punna Mantaniputta had been of great help to him during his learning period. He had taught Dhamma to the new monks and had explained to them that the "I am" conceit does not arise without a cause — namely, it is brought about through form, feeling, perceptions, mental formations, and consciousness. For a better understanding of this, the venerable Punna had given a fitting analogy:
 
"If somebody should want to see his reflection or image, he could do so only through a cause, namely a mirror or a clear body of water. In the same way do the five aggregates reflect the image of "I am." As long as one depends on them and is supported by them, so long will an "I" be reflected. Only when one does not rely on them any longer, will the image of "I" disappear." [see SN 22.83]
 
Ananda thought about this analogy again and again and ever more deeply, until he penetrated the suffering, impermanence and no-self aspects of the five aggregates, and no longer relied upon them as his support. He then began to reap the benefits of monkhood, beginning with the fruit of stream-entry.
-from "Ananda, the Guardian of the Dhamma"

They often say the aggregates are just impersonal processes. And there's a saying that a river doesn't require a river god in order to flow. I think it can help to contemplate that, combined with the teaching in the Bahiya Sutta (and SN 35.95). Because they both point to the idea that those processes that make up the aggregates will still go on working just as always, even when you're not under the impression that you're the one that's been making them work all this time. Hearing keeps hearing, thoughts come and go, the Sun rises, but you don't have to make it happen. A river isn't made to flow by some person, it's just gravity, the properties of water, etc.
